# Next.JS Link forces page reload on routing if internet connection is slow

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-router, next-link

I have a React Next.js application, and I use Next.js  components for routing.
Everything works just perfect, unless the internet connection is getting slow.

Reproduced by throttling network in browser dev tools.

If connection is slow, and you click the Link, it starts fetching next page chunk, but after several seconds transition happens like if it was a common  element. Page is completely reloaded, which is not expected for SPA.

Would you suggest any ideas?

Checked if there any other listeners on the element. But no.
Links are static without any parameters.

Comment: Hi,
We'd need you to provide the code of a minimal reproductible example of your pb to help you efficiently

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.